# how do we combine the categories with tags in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Here query is used to retrieve only 3 post related to the category.

```
$related = get_posts( array(
      'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID),
      'numberposts' => 3,
      'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
    ) );
```

But if the post is less than three at that time am in need of the  post based on tag.

Need to display 3 post by category if not have to display it by tags.

Don't know how to set the condition for that, please suggest some ideas for that.

Comment: use query_posts( 'cat=1&tag=apples' );

Comment: And Based on the post-format and tags  the post to be displayed.

$format=get_post_format();
$post_format_type="post-format-$format";
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( $post_format_type)
            )
        )
    );
by using this i retrived the post related to tags based on format.

now i have to combine everything

Comment: @VishalKamal recommending `query_posts` is like recommending someone to drink arsenic or pure sulphuric acid

Comment: can we use a relation "OR" and "AND"

Comment: You will need to run two separate queries to achive what you need. There is no other workaround here

Comment: Thankyu..but am newbie to wordpress could you suggest some example ..or else could yu suggest some idea to achieve that one..not familiar about that relation.